# Update running Dataflow pipeline with Terraform results in 'alreadyExists' error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-dataflow

We use Terraform to deploy our production pipelines (via an intermediate step that produces a template). Today we ran into this issue that reported that the pipeline (id `2020-08-18_02_25_22-424560846174449203`) could not be updated because an active job already exists. This seems kind of contradictory, as a job should be running in order for it to update.

```
Error: googleapi: Error 409: (55efe7fe364e8a95): The workflow could not be created. Causes: (9f7605bc07f0170d): There is already an active job named acc-dl-metl-ingestion-v1. If you want to  submit a second job, try again by setting a different name., alreadyExists
```

Explicitly verified the template that the template contains the `update = true` config.

Any suggestions on what could cause this?

Comment: Could you please share  your  tf file? I was checking the Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dataflow_job.html) and I did not find the update = true parameter

Comment: can you please also file a support ticket so that someone can jump in to debug what happened? Please let me know if you don't have a support account, and we can look into an alternative.